# jade if behaving inconsistent

Tags: css, express, pug

I am using expressjs, I have in my app the following:

```
app.get('/profile',index.profile);
app.get('/',index.home);
```

and in layout.jade

```
...
if typeof(username)!=='undefined'
                    li: a(href='/logout') Log Out
                else
                    li: a(href='/register') Register
...
```

My routing code is the following:

```
 exports.home = function(req,res){
if (typeof req.session.username == 'undefined')
    res.render('login',{title:'PageTitle'});
else
    res.redirect('/profile');
 };

exports.profile = function(req,res){
var show_devices = function(username,dev){
    res.render('home',{title:'Pagetutle', username: username,some other data..});
}
if (typeof req.session.username == 'undefined')
    res.redirect('/');
  ...
```

Here is my logout

```
 exports.logout = function(req,res){
req.session.destroy();
res.redirect('/');
 };
```

The first time I start my server I get in the list `Register`, when I log in I gent `Log Out`, but when I log out I also get `Log Out`. As if the `username` somehow would have survived there. How can I remove from the jade namespace the `username` variable - I think that's my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, but it feels ugly to mee.

I modify the `exports.home` like this:

```
exports.home = function(req,res){
if (typeof req.session.username == 'undefined')
    res.render('login',{title:'Smart Fridge',username:undefined});
else
    res.redirect('/profile');
};
```

And when jade checks, it finds that the type of username is undefined. Is there a better solution? I need to check if the type is undefined, because the `layout.jade` is rendered from other pages too, so I find it stupid to pass some variable every time I render a page, just to define which elements of the menu should be displayed and which not.